# How much did Israel pay the Libyan Flight 114 shootdown victims?

Tags: israel, aircraft, libya

In 1973, Israeli jets shot down [Libyan Arab Airlines Flight 114](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libyan_Arab_Airlines_Flight_114), which strayed into Sinai peninsula, then under Israeli occupation. This caused the death of 108 of 113 people on board. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libyan_Arab_Airlines_Flight_114#Aftermath),  Israel paid compensation to the victims' families. I've been trying to find out how much compensation was paid to each family.

Answer (score 2):

According to an article that published in "Haaretz" daily newspaper(January 2003) The Israeli government paid 30,000 USD to families of victims, and 10,000 - 30,000 to survivors who injured.

As described, the Israeli government announced it will pay as a good will even though that the responsibility and the fault in this case was on the Libyan aircraft captain.

Few words about "Haaretz":
"Haaretz" known as a left-wing daily newspaper

[Here is a link to the article(in Hebrew)](http://www.haaretz.co.il/misc/1.858048)

Comment: Are those USD figures 2003 adjusted for inflation? If so, are they adjusted to 2003 or 2016 dollars?